# Singleton design pattern in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic2

**Singleton design pattern** in ionic 2.
Can anyone tell me how to make singleton design pattern in ionic.

```
export class example{

private constructor(){

}

}
```

Please help I don't how to make singleton class in ionic

Comment: ionic 1 or ionic 2?

Comment: ionic 2 please  help for the same

Comment: do you mean a provider?

Comment: I don't know what we call singleton design pattern in ionic but please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just provide it as service in `AppModule`

```
@Injectable()
export class Example {
  constructor(){}
}
```

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    DetailsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    DetailsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    Example,  // <<<=== your class
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and Angular DI will take care that the same instance is injected everywhere.

Comment: this is same as sigleton design pattern

Comment: No, but there should not be a need for the singleton design pattern. If you want to actually know about the singelton design pattern, you should remove the angular2 and ionic tags from your question and add `typescript` and `design-patterns`, singleton is not related to Angular or Ionic in any way.

Comment: where should I declare example class in my project

Comment: I don't know about Ionic project structure.

Comment: So where to write  example class because it giving error cannot find name example

Comment: As I said, I don't know Ionic. If you insist to use the lowercase `example` as class name, then the provider should also be `lowercase`.